# Create gradient overlay on background image with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create black gradient overlay on background image. But I have a problem. Background image always random and responsive ready (width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100%;). So I can`t just put gradient to bottom with fixed height. Is it possible to do that with css or jquery? Thanks!

My HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/aobnuox7/

`<div style="background:url(http://images.nintendolife.com/reviews/2011/02/panda_craze_dsiware/large.jpg) #000 no-repeat top center;   width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left:0;  z-index:1;  ">
</div>`

http://pbrd.co/1v1cavd - screenshot of what I need to do

Comment: It would be easier to just do it in photoshop than in css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shadow that fades from the bottom to around the middle why not use `box-shadow: inset`? You can find some useful generators online to get yourself started and then modify them as you need them to be. I'd suggest putting the box-shadow in an after pseudo class also.